# Calling value in the same object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I'm making this small little application that allows users to enter a command to resize their div.

When doing this I want to make it easier by making a shorthand option that simply calls the same value from the full name, but this returns undefined.

Changing `this.small` to `sizes.small` returns the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
var sizes = {
    // Full names for sizes
    small      : [200,  150],
    medium     : [500,  350],
    large      : [1000, 700],
    fullscreen : [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight],

    // Shorthand for sizes
    s : this.small,    
    m : this.medium,        
    l : this.large,     
    f : this.fullscreen        
}

// The following two calls should return the exact same result
console.log(sizes.small);   // array[200, 150]
console.log(sizes.s);       // undefined
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136174/should-one-use-getters-and-setters-for-private-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference properties that way. Here is one way to achieve what you want:

```
var sizes = new (function() {
  this.small = [200,  150];
  this.s = this.small;
})();

console.log(sizes.small);
console.log(sizes.s);
```

See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8A8uw/).

Comment: This fixed my problem and kept it as close to the original, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An object literal doesn’t change any contexts; it’s not a function. It’s more like an expression. `sizes.small` won’t work either, since although `sizes` is declared, it hasn’t been assigned a value at the time you’re reading it (which is to create the object that gives it a value).

You can assign the properties afterwards:

```
var sizes = {
    // Full names for sizes
    small      : [200,  150],
    medium     : [500,  350],
    large      : [1000, 700],
    fullscreen : [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]      
};

// Shorthand for sizes
sizes.s = sizes.small;
sizes.m = sizes.medium;
sizes.l = sizes.large;
sizes.f = sizes.fullscreen;
```

Answer (score 2):

make "s" be a function that returns "this.small"

That is,

```
var sizes = {
    small      : [200,  150],
    s : function() {return this.small}
}
```

Comment: This literally outputs `function () {return this.small}` in the console as a string. I guess the function assigning doesn't work like that.

Comment: To expound: "s" is essentially a getter method here. if you wanted to do things the "jquery way", you could have s accept a parameter; if that parameter is not null, it's a setter and you can set this.small to that value. If it's undefined, you could return this.small.

Comment: Correct! Not very experienced with objects here :D

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to access other values in object before it is created.

You can try with:

```
var sizes = {
    // Full names for sizes
    small      : [200,  150],
    medium     : [500,  350],
    large      : [1000, 700],
    fullscreen : [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight],
}

sizes.s = sizes.small;
sizes.m = sizes.medium;       
sizes.l = sizes.large;
sizes.f = sizes.fullscreen;
```

Comment: I've already tried this, I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined

Comment: @Paradoxis I've edited my answer. Recent answer works only in Chrome console.

Comment: @hsz: Did you perhaps run it twice?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript

> this

always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. When we define, for example, a function in a page, its owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of JavaScript.