# Why use functions that only returns parameter

Tags: javascript

I know it's a very basic question but why would this approach be a better way to use

```
this.param = doc('someData');
function doc(opendoc){
    return opendoc;
}
```

instead of

```
this.param = openDoc;
```

I'm working on an existing project and they constantly use this approuch.

Comment: Placeholder? Dummy callback? Refactoring gone awry? Lack of coffee? PEBKAC? Id-Ten-T?

Comment: It's not a dummy callback for sure, it's just a way that variables are defined, i edited the code

Comment: in the first example the param references the function not the variable opendoc.

Comment: I changed the code @Meiko

Comment: maybe they wanted to implement something like a setter... but did'nt get it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136174/should-one-use-getters-and-setters-for-private-variables

Comment: I vote for "Refactoring gone awry" as @deceze said

Comment: It's not the first time that i see this approach, i cannot seem to find a lot of toppics about it on why to use it. The only thing i can think of is that perhaps they want to be prepared for filtering or so...

Comment: It's very silly to do, but I'm assuming that it's in the case they _ever_ want to change the logic of `openDoc`, but surely they could just set `openDoc` to something else when they set it?

Comment: I'm sorry for all of your time, i just tought that i was missing something and it was perhaps a better way to do and who knows secure the code more this way. It seems like they just made it harder than it should be.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) is fundamental because it acts as a unit (`1`) in the algebra of functions, that is

```
Id • f = f
```

<sup>where • is the composition operator, this means that Id(f(x)) == f(x)</sup>

In programming, it's useful as a placeholder or a default value when a function argument is required. Example:

```
 Id = function(x) { return x }

 function processData(data, sortBy) {
      // if no sorting function provided, sort by element itself
      data.sort(sortBy || Id);
      ....
 }
```

It's also good style to use `Id` as a wrapper function when a semantic type conversion takes place, e.g.

```
SearchResult = Id

...

http.get(function(rawData) {
     this.searchResult = SearchResult(rawData)
```

instead of just

```
this.searchResult = rawData
```

which might be confusing for the reader.

Comment: BTW, instead of explaining it with mathematical concepts I would otherwise explain it telling the OP that maybe these are closures to later be used as predicates in other functions..........

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: "I would otherwise explain" -- feel free to do so, the add answer button is right here vvvv ;)

Comment: It's just a criticism against people like you that mix programming with maths very often :\ IMHO, I would say that if someone would ask for how it can turn on a TV, no one would answer based on physics or electrical engineering principles :D

Comment: I liked your mathematical introduction :-P.

Comment: As I [said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794820/why-use-functions-that-only-returns-parameter#comment59259403_35794820)... Id-Ten-T... Err, wait... I-den-T-T.

Comment: @deceze: do you have a question?

Comment: Just trying to make a lame dad joke. Go right along, good sir.

Comment: @deceze: ah, ok, lol.